# Android: Using temporary compatibility workaround for usage of memorybase private API

Tags: android, performance

I just recently started working on Android and whenever I click on anything it throws "using temporary compatibility workaround for usage of memorybase private API" in the LogCat. I am unsure what exactly it is trying to tell me. Is it saying that it is close to memory capacity? 
Thank you for the help, for I am very new to android development!

Comment: Try another device or the emulator; this sounds like it may be yet another example of how many Android devices routinely spew alarming sounding log messages (and on occasion, even outright errors/crashes) from factory code, which have little or nothing to do with an application you might be developing/using at the same time.  Or you can edit into your question the surrounding logcat message, being sure to include the launch of the application you are actually interest in, so we can see the PID of your application's process vs. that of whatever is logging this warning.

Comment: You were right about the different devices. I tried it on 3 other different emulators and the error did not show. Its nice that it at least doesn't crash on me and just makes me think my app was using too much memory!